# No handles with labels found to put in legend error while plotting a graph

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-science

I am trying to draw a graph, but getting the error "No handles with labels found to put in legend.
"

```
def generate_plot_1(df):
data=df.drop('2013',axis=1)
plot1_data=data.groupby('Commodity').mean()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(plot1_data.T)
plot1_data.legend()
plt.title('Average Price')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Average price')
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Please edit your post to correct the indentation of your code, include sufficient code to be able to reproduce the error, and the complete error message that you receive.

Comment: Maybe adding a label works? As in `plt.plot(plot1_data.T, label='Added label')`?

Comment: You're better off dropping everything after the `.groupby` and then using `ax = plot1_data.T.plot(figsize=(8, 7), title='Average Price', ylabel='Average Price', xlabel='Month')` to plot the dataframe directly.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney worked in both ways. Thanks!!!